# Android: Why is my land\layout not working as shown in design panel?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app that is a simple music player that allows for screen rotation. I used the option "Layout Variants->Switch to layout-land" to create a landscape layout. I use a constrained layout that links all the buttons and progress bar. However, when I launch the emulator and rotate my screen, the layout does not seem to change from how it is in the portrait orientation. In my manifest I have `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize` so that I do not have to deal with activity dying. My layouts in my folder are under app/res/layout/activity_main.xml. Here are my layout codes (I do not have any configuration overrides in my main java folder) :

This is a homework assignment, please do not give me direct answers.

[image]

[image]

layout\activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Garnet"
    tools:context="com.example.davidmiller.assignment4.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FEAR THE SPEAR!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Seminole Uprising"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="149dp"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU Cheer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:onClick="playSong" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="4th Quarter Fanfare"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Gold and Garnet"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU Fight Song"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU Victory Song"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU War Chant"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:onClick="playSong" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pause"
        android:onClick="pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/play"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stop"
        android:onClick="stop"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:onClick="play"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

land\activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Garnet"
    tools:context="com.example.davidmiller.assignment4.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FEAR THE SPEAR!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Seminole Uprising"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU Cheer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:onClick="playSong" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="4th Quarter Fanfare"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Gold and Garnet"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU Fight Song"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU Victory Song"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="FSU War Chant"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:onClick="playSong"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pause"
        android:onClick="pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/play"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stop"
        android:onClick="stop"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:onClick="play"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen in landscape? The 7 song buttons are too tall to show the play buttons

Comment: @cricket_007 I actually have changed the layout for landscape orientation, but when I rotate my screen it seems like it is actually not changing to that layout. It seems like it keeps the same layout as portrait

Answer (score 0):

If you want the app to automatically change it's layout when the device is rotated, you have to delete the `android:configchanges=orientation` command. Of course, your app will then be destroyed and re launched, and you will have to re-configure it.